# numerical integration - quadrature of second degree

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Short Task: How can I find a interpolational quadrature formula with 2 points which interpolates all polynomials of second degree exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible in dimension 1, as in superior dimensions, polynomials have more degrees of freedom.
 For arbitrary degree, you may look for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature.

In the case of integrating a polynomial of degree 2 (or 3 or less) over $[-1,1]$, you should take the points $\pm\sqrt{1/3}$ with unitary weights.

Comment: What if we don't have a given interval?

Comment: you should make a linear transformation to $[-1,1]$:
$(2*[a,b]-(a+b))/(b-a)$ should to the trick